# With langchain, I want to reuse the result of a tools from history

Tags: langchain

I have a tool and a chatbot with history.
I can use a tool to resolve a question.
The question and answers were in history.

But, if I ask the same question, the tool in invoked another time, without the usage of history. I need to declare the description of the tools with a magic trick?